# Get the client Ip address in RMI Server when cleint makes a call registry.lookup("RMI Server")

Tags: rmi

I want to get the ip address of each client in the server side for which the server return a stub. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

See RemoteServer.getClientHost(). You can invoke that inside your remote method implementations. You can't get it when they do the Registry lookup however.