# Java RMI: Determining Caller process from Callee

Tags: java, rmi

Is there any way to determine the caller process in Callee remote method.

Suppose there are 3 clients and a server and server has one remote method which is called by all the clients. Is it possible to determine which of the client process called the remote method at runtime? (other than passing the process name in the method)

```
Server
void callMe(){//remote method
System.out.println("I was called by Client : " + ? );

}


Client
...
...

server.callMe();
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Determine remote client IP address for Java RMI call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590257/determine-remote-client-ip-address-for-java-rmi-call) and [Get the client Ip address in RMI Server when cleint makes a call registry.lookup("RMI Server")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623053/get-the-client-ip-address-in-rmi-server-when-cleint-makes-a-call-registry-lookup)